# React-Redux connect() not updating component even when the state is changed without mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/goldbullet/pen/EyJQbp), where `store.subscribe()` works and `connect()` doesn't work. Specifically, the component doesn't get updated with the new props. I suspected state mutation as I thought that connect()'s shallow equality check might be ignoring the change. But, I'm using `Immutable.js` for the state change in the reducer, and I also did my own ref check in my subscribe method and it is even shallowly different for every update. I feel like something obvious must be missing here...

Component:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  alerts: state.alerts
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onAlert: (type, autoHide, message) => 
    dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_ALERT', payload: { message, type, autoHide } })
});

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Reducer:

```
const alertsReducer = (alerts=Immutable.List(), { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type){
    case 'SHOW_ALERT':
      if (!payload.message || R.trim(payload.message).length === 0){          
        throw new Error('Message cannot be empty.');
      }
      return alerts.push(payload);
    default:
      return alerts;
  }
};
```

Store:

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({ alerts: alertsReducer }), applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk.default));
```

Render:

```
//** THIS DOESN'T WORK
// ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedApp /></Provider>, document.getElementById('main'));

//** THIS WORKS
store.subscribe(()=>{
  render();
});
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App {...store.getState()} onAlert={
        (type, autoHide, message) => store.dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_ALERT', payload: { message, type, autoHide } })
      }/>, document.getElementById('main'));
};
render();
```

Is this because the top level state object still has the same reference? I tried removing `Immutable.js` and made the entire state the array with the reducer returning a new array every time. That still didn't work.

Versions:

```
react-redux@4.4.5
redux@3.5.2
react@15.3.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you open the console , there will be the error

> addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might
>   be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a
>   component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React
>   loaded

to solve it you should choose between https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-with-addons.min.js
and
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js, because React should be added to page once.

after that you need to add Provider from react-redux. Also you need to add key props in your lists.

**changed pen** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXLQLv?editors=0010